# Using Kafka without RabbitMQ

Tags: masstransit

I am testing MassTransit with Kafka without RabbitMQ

I need a `IBusControl`, can i use `bus.UsingInMemory()`?
Is it safe to use for Kafka ITopicProducers?
Does features like scheduling/sagas will work with Kafka or with InMemory bus?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an in-memory bus with Kafka, but realize that the in-memory bus is not durable. The only reason you would want to use it is because you want to consume/produce Kafka messages without using an accompanying broker.

Sagas work with Kafka just fine, since sagas are a type of consumer.

Scheduling is not supported with Kafka, since it isn't a broker. Using scheduling with in-memory is not recommended outside of unit tests.

Comment: I mean, can i schedule messages TO Kafka. For example using quartz and sending delayed messages to kafka

Comment: No, you can't. You could schedule a message to a broker-based consumer, which could then produce a message to a Kafka Topic, but you can't send from quartz directly to Kafka using MassTransit.

Comment: Is it possible feature request or restricted by design?

Comment: It's by design, nothing I plan to change.

Comment: I found a problem using sagas with Kafka. Sagas can schedule something on timeout (examples), but scheduling is working with bus, not riders. So it is a bit dangerous to use in memory bus and Kafka

Comment: How about using SQL transport? If you already have a server at least it's not adding anything extra like RabbitMQ

Comment: SQL is not a supported transport for MassTransit.